# partial view into master _layout in Asp.net mvc 4 razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i am try to add _partial view into master _layout but it get error, i use _partial view for newsletter into fotter for every rendering page user can subscribe news letter easily so i use partial view in Layout Razor in mvc 4

Comment: What error? And what is your code?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_PartialViewName.cshtml");
```

> you can use this razor syntax according to your partial view location
>   in your footer this syntax renders your partial view in your desired place